# How to fix errors with variables returning undefined

Tags: r

I'm trying to parse through a JSON file, this file has thousands of individual JSON objects but for testing purposes I am working with only 3 rows of JSON objects.  What I've run into is, I've declared a function in R and using the rjson package, but when I try to execute the R file in RStudio, I get an error in the console saying that my function is undefined.

I've tried calling the function via the console, and executing via the R script file. I've also read through a couple tutorials as I've never worked in R before.

```
library("rjson")

parseJsonData <- function (fileName) 
{
  result <- fromJSON(file = fileName)
  jsonFrame <- as.data.frame(result)
  return(jsonFrame)
}

parseJsonData("testData.json")
```

I would expect to have a data frame returned and print to the console window.

**UPDATE**:
Seems to be an issue with the file format, which I don't have control over unfortunately, the file provided is a json file, but it is formatted as having 10k individual JSON objects, not a list of objects.

For example, this is how the file is formatted inside the testData.json

{"name":"test1", "value":"1"}

{"name":"test2", "value":"2"}

{"name":"test3", "value":"3"}

{"name":"test4", "value":"4"}

{"name":"test5", "value":"5"}

Comment: Replace `<=` with `<-`.

Comment: Thanks! I replaced those and still get the same error though...

Comment: To be clear: if you copy and paste the code above into your console it says that `parseJsonData` is undefined?

Comment: I think it was an issue with how I was calling it, I'm running into a different issue now though.

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
 
 Hide Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection 
5.file(con, "r") 
4.readLines(file, warn = FALSE) 
3.paste(readLines(file, warn = FALSE), collapse = "") 
2.fromJSON(file = fileName) 
1.parseJsonData("testData.json")

Comment: can you check that the file is present by running `list.files()` in console?

Comment: That was the issue, I thought it was in the correct path but apparently I did not have it in the R Project so it wasn't able to find it. On top of not knowing exactly how to run my R script from R Studio...

Thank you for the help!